# Installed extensions are not showing extension manager open cart

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

I'd installed Paytm extension in my Open cart website, it says extension is installed and i can view in install history but i can not view in extension manager, 
[install history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv62J.png)

i have refreshed modification still no luck.
i have tried razor payment gateway too and the same happens
i'm on opencart version 3.0.2.0
Please help. Thank you

Comment: if you have installed ocmod (xxx.ocmod.zip) extension, maybe file for installing not properly created. You need to check  and enable, if not enabled  permissions in admin dashboard system/users/user group for administrator. And then check directly  in extension section.

Comment: yes i have enabled all permission for admin still nothing happens

Comment: Seems this is not default OC extension, so ask developer of this extension regarding issue.